# MongoDB: Speed of field ("inside record") search in comporation with speed of search in "global scope"

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

My question may be not very good formulated because I haven't worked with MongoDB yet, so I'd want to know one thing.

I have an object (record/document/anything else) in my database - in global scope.

And have a really huge array of other objects in this object.

So, what about speed of search in global scope vs search "inside" object? Is it possible to index all "inner" records?

Thanks beforehand.

So, like this

```
users: {
..
user_maria:
{
  age: "18",
  best_comments :
    {
      goodnight:"23rr",
      sleeptired:"dsf3"
     ..
    }
}

user_ben:
{
  age: "18",
  best_comments :
    {
      one:"23rr",
      two:"dsf3"
     ..
    }
}
```

So, how can I make it fast to find user_maria->best_comments->goodnight (index context of collections "best_comment") ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct schema. Storing comments like that seems like a rather bad idea.

Comment: When I was reading MongoDB docs few years ago I found that they highly recommend to store all things refer to this record "inside" it. (This model is not very valid - I understand what you mean. Imagine that I have a copy of best users comments inside it's own profile record to show it fast. Better?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your example schema is very questionable. If you want to embed comments (which is a big if), you'd want to store them in an array for appropriate indexing. Also, post your schema in JSON format so we don't have to parse the whole name/value thing :

```
db.users {
    name:"maria",
    age: 18,
    best_comments: [
        {
            title: "goodnight",
            comment: "23rr"
        },
        {
            title: "sleeptired",
            comment: "dsf3"
        }
    ]
}
```

With that schema in mind you can put an index on name and best_comments.title for example like so :

```
db.users.ensureIndex({name:1, 'best_comments.title:1})
```

Then, when you want the query you mentioned, simply do

```
db.users.find({name:"maria", 'best_comments.title':"first"})
```

And the database will hit the index and will return this document very fast.

Now, all that said. Your schema is very questionable. You mention you want to query specific comments but that requires either comments being in a seperate collection or you filtering the comments array app-side. Additionally having huge, ever growing embedded arrays in documents can become a problem. Documents have a 16mb limit and if document increase in size all the time mongo will have to continuously move them on disk.

My advice :

- Put comments in a seperate collection
- Either do document per comment or make comment bucket documents (say,
  100 comments per document)
  Read up on Mongo/NoSQL schema design. You always query for root documents so if you end up needing a small part of a large embedded structure you need to reexamine your schema or you'll be pumping huge documents over the connection and require app-side filtering.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I was reading MongoDB docs few years ago, as I said, so I forgot JSON and MongoDB little bit, so I was recognising if there's any functionality to do things I was talking about.. What you meant saying "You always query for root documents"? If I query `{name:"maria", 'best_comments.title':"first"}` I query the whole `maria` object before parsing it? Well, I have thing like this: I have thousands of "worlds" in my system - each has it's own users base, interior and etc. I was thinking of making each "world" as a single record with "users", "rooms" fields. You thing it's a bad  idea?

Comment: Yes. You'll want to be able to query users seperately so having them all embedded into a world document is not optimal. Additionally you might hit the 16mb document limit.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for saying me that - I'd fall into this trap. So, you recommend to use separate users table and have user field "world" - right?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. But for some reasons there are lots of examples in mongo docs in which they store comments with the page they are related to. So, what would you say about storing, for example, long-long comments history inside page document they are related to. And I haven't really caught, if I query `({page:"first"}, {"comments"}).limit(10).skip(10)` - I pump the hole document over connection?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question but it sounds like you have one record with many attributes.

record = {'attr1':1, 'attr2':2, etc.}

You can create an index on any single attribute or any combination of attributes.  Also, you can create any number of indices on a single collection (MongoDB collection == MySQL table), whether or not each record in the collection has the attributes being indexed on.

edit: I don't know what you mean by 'global scope' within MongoDB.  To insert any data, you must define a database and collection to insert that data into.

Database 'Example':

Collection 'table1':

```
   records: {a:1,b:1,c:1}

            {a:1,b:2,d:1}

            {a:1,c:1,d:1}

   indices:

            ensureIndex({a:ascending, d:ascending})   <- this will index on a, then by d;  the fact that record 1 doesn't have an attribute 'd' doesn't matter, and this will increase query performance
```

edit 2:

Well first of all, in your table here, you are assigning multiple values to the attribute "name" and "value".  MongoDB will ignore/overwrite the original instantiations of them, so only the final ones will be included in the collection.

I think you need to reconsider your schema here.  You're trying to use it as a series of key value pairs, and it is not specifically suited for this (if you really want key value pairs, check out Redis).

Check out: http://www.jonathanhui.com/mongodb-query

Comment: I should mention that there is a inverse relationship between the number of attributes in a record and query speed on those records.  ie. a collection containing 100 attributes per record will be queried slower than a collection containing 10 attributes per record.

Comment: I've updated question to make it cleaner to understand what I mean. Have a look, please. Also, you meant something like: speed of search it some scope depends on amount of records in this scope ? Or that .. if I add more attributes into object A - it will course decrease of speed of object B request? (If there are in a single scope?)

Comment: I meant that if you have two collections, A and B, and records in collection A have 100 attributes, and records in collection B have 10 attributes, then a query on A will take longer than a query on B.

Comment: Right. I caught about attributes. Won't you have a look at my question again after new update?